# Sequelize - How to add/upsert row with same primary key of soft deleted row

Tags: sequelize.js, upsert, soft-delete

I'm using sequelize ORM. I have a model for a table where we have soft deletion enabled via `paranoid: true`.

**Question:** Is there a way to do an upsert such that if the object already exists in the table but is soft deleted, it will just clear the deletedAt column?

Sample setup: `model.js`

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  dbName,
  username,
  password,
  {
    host,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port
  }
)

const model =  sequelize.define(
  'sample_table',
  {
    uid: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(60),
      allowNull: false
      primaryKey: true
    },
    deletedAt: {
      type: Sequelize.Date,
      allowNull: true,
      default: null
    }
  },
  {
    tableName: 'sample_table'
    deletedAt: true,
    paranoid: true
  }
)
```

Sample usage:

```
const model = require('./model.js')

(async () => {
  const myModel = await model.create({
    uid: 'sample-uid'
  })

  await myModel.destroy()

  // error is encountered because uid already exists
  await model.create({
    uid: 'sample-uid'
  })
})()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you should do it manually (e.g. add a catch to create method and using `.restore()` to clear the deletedAt column).

Or you can add a primary key on uid + deletedAt and your code should work without errors.

```
const model = require('./model.js')

(async () => {
  const myModel = await model.create({
    uid: 'sample-uid'
  })

  await myModel.destroy()

  // if primary key uid and deletedAt then no error here
  await model.create({
    uid: 'sample-uid'
  })
})()
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing your first suggestion. It's actually for an association generated method, I extended the generated methods functionality in the prototype. The second suggestion would also work on my case since it won't be for a highly populated table.